# How can I create a "Revise" button that saves user input?

Tags: jsf

I'm working on a JSF2/Java web application with select items like this checkbox below, that gets submitted when the form is submitted.

```
    <p class="geoSearchFilterHeader">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{searchBean.byNewStates}" 
            immediate="true" 
            onclick="submit();" 
            valueChangeListener="#{searchBean.geoAreaSelectChanged}">   
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>Search By State or Province
    </p> 

   <h:panelGroup rendered="#{searchBean.byState}">
       State (ctrl-click to select multiple states):<br />
       <h:selectManyListbox value="#{searchBean.states}" size="2" immediate="true"> 
       <f:selectItems value="#{searchBean.stateItems}"></f:selectItems>                             

       </h:selectManyListbox>
   </h:panelGroup>
```

If I wanted to create something like a "revise" button once the form has been submitted, how would I go about rendering a form that is pre-populated?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Where will the result inputs be saved ? in the same form after submitting ?

Comment: And what does your revise button do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *how would I go about rendering a form that is pre-populated?*

Just preset the model values (those properties bound to `value` attribute of input components) in bean's `@PostConstruct` method.

E.g.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    byNewStates = true;
    states = Arrays.asList("NY", "CA", "FL");
}
```

You can if necessary use `<f:viewParam>` to preset (and convert/validate) them based on request parameters.